# Best Practice: Call .Net Function after webpage is visible for the user

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm in search of some best practices. I have a webpage asp.net (a loading page as you will).
Once this page is loaded (and visible to the user) i want to execute a function that might last some seconds.
problem is, how do i launch this function?
I've tried loadComplete (event),unload (event) , working with timeout (javascript to poll itself with json) and even the timer-class (.Net). Could anyone point out an alternative/ best pratices to perform this kind of action?

Comment: Your .NET function is executed on the server. So, you can make an AJAX call to your .NET function after the page has loaded

Comment: Yes, by the time the page is rendered all methods have finished execution. Like @Shreyas said, you'll need to make a client-side call to some web service sitting on the server.

Comment: Yes the combination of Ajax - Jquery did resolve it for me. Now i can simply call the function without reloading the entire page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work the way that you are trying to do it. To understand why you have to understand the concept of webservers:

Webservers use some code (PHP, ASP.NET, ...) to generate dynamical HTML code that is beeing sent to the client. This process works in the following steps (in case of ASP.NET)

1. Client requests something from the server.
2. Server generates html (that's your ASP.NET / C# code)
3. Server sends HTML to client
4. The browser on the client receives the HTML and displays it.

**So your ASP.NET code is only running in step 2**. This makes it impossible to catch the event when the client has rendered his page in his browser. However there is client-side technology called [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). You can make AJAX calls using javascript (that runs in the browser of the client).

So for example you can create a javascript function that sends a second request to the server when the html was loaded in the client, and executes some function on the server.
For this you will need a webservice on the server that will serve as a interface between the javascript and your C# code. 
A easy way to create webservices is to use [WCF webservices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb412178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you have any further questions feel free to comment on this answer.

Comment: This is how many software packages run maintenance on themselves. If it is time to run a maintenance process, such as cleaning something up in the database, instead of putting it in the page load (increasing loading times for the poor user), they simply  put an AJAX call at the bottom of the body so it's loaded absolutely last after the page is already being mostly displayed in the browser. Then that executes the maintenance call, with no response returned. Some of the more clever implementations actually only do this for search engine spiders (bots) so users aren't affected.

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET in combination with C#, I don't see how it should be necessary to use this technique. If you know C# you can create a windows service that will do the maintenance. And as you are obviously already running a windows server (when running ASP.NET) where you could deploy that webservice it won't create you any costs to get the infrastracture.

Comment: Using Ajax (from jquery) ive managed to resolve the issue. Thanks for the hint! the second call appends an extra parameter to url! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @RononDex I think you're not considering Azure-type single-site hosting situations.